# Não consigo executar DELETE no SQL quando submeto form via POST no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, delete

Tenho este código e gostaria de apagar uma lista de users quando o form fosse submetido, mas não está funcionando: Alguma dica?

```
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO users (name, email, joined) VAlUES ("'.$_POST['username'].'", "' .$_POST['email'].'", NOW())') or die ('daw');
    echo ('Cool<br>');
    unset($_POST['username']);
    unset($_POST['email']);

}
else {
    echo ('<strong style="color:red;">FILLLL</strong>');
}
$sql = ('SELECT * FROM users');
$mydata = mysql_query($sql, $con);

function deleteAll() {

        mysql_query('DELETE FROM users');

}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

    <form action ="register.php" method="POST">
        Username:
        <br>
        <input type ="text" name ="username" value=""/>
        <br><br>
        Email:
        <br>
        <input type ="text" name ="email" value=""/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Register!">
    </form>
    <table>
    <?php
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)) {
        echo ('<tr>
              <td>' .ucfirst($result['name']). '</td>
              <td>' .$result['email']. '</td>
              <td>' .date('F j, Y, H:i ', strtotime($result['joined'])).'</td>
            </tr>');
    }
    ?>
    </table>
<input type="button" value="deleteAll" class="botao" onclick="deleteAll();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só para saber, não olhei todo o código ainda, mas o usuário que esta acessando o banco de dados, tem o privilégio de executar o delete?

Comment: Na realidade é só curiosidade, estou a estudar php

Comment: Certo... outro, olhando o comando delete tbm esta errado.. É DELETE FROM <tabela> [WHERE chave=valor]. E tbm não se passa para uma função dessa forma que vc passou no action. Da uma olhada melhor nisso

Comment: Obgado, e esse 'valor' seria o quê? a chave é o id... o que eu quero é delete a todos logo. Eu na action usei esta dica: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390488/call-form-submit-action-from-php-function-on-same-page-doesnt-work

Comment: Este valor é referente a uma chave específica que deseja deletar. No seu caso, DELET FROM users é o correto porque deseja deletar todos os usuários. No seu código existe 2 tags <form> o que você poderia retirar e colocar apenas <input type="button" value="deleteAll" class="botao" onclick="deleteAll();" />

Comment: Fiz o update em cima, mas não está a resultar

Comment: Lembre que q vc é obrigado a passar a conexão para `mysql_query()` quando essa instrução está dentro de uma função.

Comment: Quando eu coloquei entre [] significa que não é obrigatório, bastaria fazer o DELETE FROM users. Mas para funcionar vc deve seguir a ideia da resposta do @NULL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forma que sua query sql foi escrita está errônea, a syntax correta é: `DELETE FROM TABELA`

Para chamar a função **PHP** da forma que você está tentando fazer, você precisa por sua função dentro da chamada de um [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) (Recebe argumentos via URL), mudar o **form method** para **GET** e  alterar o valor do **input submit** para `deleteAll`.

Exemplo:

```
if($_GET["action"] == "deleteAll")
{
    // Sua função aqui
}
```